# How to make a windows 10 install file

Tags: node.js, .net, windows, powershell, msbuild

I want to know if Windows offers an installation script or tool to install node runtime and my node js code.

This is what I want to:

- install node
- download the compiled node app
- use `pm2` to run the code like `node app.js`
- make this as a window service and starts on boot

The can download this installation file. Click on it once, all this will run. Like a bat file or power shell script.

Comment: This looks like a task for an installer. Try, say, [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this extensively, but it should at least give you some ideas for getting started.

- Use `Invoke-WebRequest` to download the Node.js Windows installer
- Use `Start-Process` and `msiexec.exe` to install it
- With Node.js installed, you should be able to use `npm` to install the
  latest version of PM2
- Use `Invoke-WebRequest` again to download the Node app file
- Instead of a custom Windows service, consider creating a *scheduled
  task* that runs at logon with `New-JobTrigger` and `Register-ScheduledJob`

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.1/node-v14.17.1-x64.msi" -OutFile ".\node-v14.17.1-x64.msi"
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/i node-v14.17.1-x64.msi /quiet"

npm install pm2@latest -g

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "node-app-url" -OutFile ".\app.js"

$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn -RandomDelay "00:00:30"
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock { pm2 start app.js } -Name "RunNodeAppAtLogon"
```

Comment: This will be a power shell script? Is possible to convert or build this script into an executable file? `exe` or some installation file with progress bar? I want to make this look good. 

Also why did you recommend scheduled tasks over Windows service?

Comment: `Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/i node-v14.17.1-x64.msi /quiet"` does not work. I don't get any installation errors. But the node is not installed.

Comment: Try it without the `/quiet` switch and see if you get any feedback on what is happening. You can also add `/L*V <path-to-log>` at the end to write installation output to a log file.

Comment: Take a look at the following linked guide for information on converting PS1 to EXE [(LINK)](https://adamtheautomator.com/ps1-to-exe/). For a progress bar, the `Write-Progress` cmdlet should work [(LINK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-5.1). Lastly, I'd recommend a _Scheduled Task_ over a _Service_ because it should be simpler to create & implement, and since the execution frequency on this should be quite low, there's no reason to have memory tied up in a _Service_.